# Finding number of distinct primes: a paradoxical solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, solution-verification

Let $a$, $b$, be primes such that the difference between their squares is prime. How many distinct values of $b$ are there?

This problem basically asks for distinct solutions to:

$a^2 - b^2 = p$, where $p$ is prime

or equivalently:

$$(a + b)(a - b) = p$$

Since a prime has only two factors, $1$ and itself, $a - b$ is $1$

($a + b$ can't be $1$ since no primes satisfy that equation)

So, $a$ and $b$ are consecutive, there's only one pair of consecutive primes, so one solution, easy.

But, if we go back to $(a + b)(a - b) = p,$

since $a - b$ is $1,$ $a + b$ is $p$

or $b + b + 1 = 2b + 1$ is prime

Here, there are actually infinitely many values of b which would yield a prime(every prime is of the form $2q + 1$).

Can someone point out the error in this? There has to be something I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: “$2b+1$ is prime” is *necessariy*, but not sufficient, to satisfy the condition. Your error is assuming that because you can conclude that if you have a solution then $b$ and $2b+1$ are prime, that means that *whenever* $b$ and $2b+1$ are prime you will have a solution. That does not follow. You also need $b+1$ to be prime (because $a=b+1$ is supposed to be a prime).

Comment: You should not say "there are actually infinite values of $b$" when you mean "there are infinitely many values of $b$." The phrase "infinite values of $b$," in the language of mathematicians, means "values of $b$, each one of which by itself is an infinite value of $b$." Also, see my edits for proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s nothing paradoxical here. The only reason that you know that $a+b=2b+1$ is that you’ve already deduced that $a-b=1$. Thus, you can’t conclude that **every** prime of the form $2b+1$ yields a solution: it’s only the ones for which $b$ and $b-1$ are both prime, and the only one of those is $b=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $2b+1$ is prime, but then it must also satisfy $a-b=1$. And since $a$ and $b$ are primes anyway, there can be only one solution to them. The reasoning on $2b+1$ needs to take into account conditions previously established – and said reasoning adds nothing to the solution.